# Why I have this error on parsing Block of YAML?

Tags: java, spring, jackson, yaml

I have this block of YAML:

```yaml
- operationId: "getG"
  applicationName: "c"

- operationId: "get"
  applicationName: "c"
```

And actually I want to parse it with Jackson Library of YAML and I have this code:

```java
public class YamlProcessor {

    ListYamlEntries> entries;
}
```

```java
@Getter //lombok
@Setter //lombok
public class YamlEntries {

    @JsonProperty("applicationName")
    String applicationName;

    @JsonProperty("operationId")
    String operationId;

}
```

```java
public YamlProcessor yamlParser(String file) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
        objectMapper.findAndRegisterModules();
        YamlProcessor yamlEntries = objectMapper.readValue(new File(file), YamlProcessor.class);

        yamlEntries.getEntries().forEach(valuesOfYaml -> {
                log.info("applicationName: " + valuesOfYaml.getApplicationName());
                log.info("operationId: " + valuesOfYaml.getOperationId());

        });

        return yamlEntries;
    }
```

But I get this error and I can't figure it out why:

```
Cannot deserialize instance of `[....objects.YamlEntries;` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (File); line: 10, column: 1]
```

Can anyone figure it out and help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly what you want to parse, but the yaml you have posted should be parsed in a
`List<YamlEntries>` instead of `List<Map<String, YamlEntries>>`

If you want to create a list of maps your yaml should be something like:

```
 - key1:
     operationId: "getG"
     applicationName: "c"
   key2:
     operationId: "getG"
     applicationName: "c"
    

 - otherkey1:
     operationId: "get"
     applicationName: "c"
   otherkey2:
     operationId: "getG"
     applicationName: "c"
```

If you want to parse a `List<YamlEntries>` this should work for you.

in the yaml you have to have something like

```
entries:
  - operationId: "getG"
    applicationName: "c"

  - operationId: "get"
    applicationName: "c"
```

And then a class like this to map the properties into a List of YamlEntries:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "entries")
public class Endpoints {
  private List<YamlEntries> yamlEntries;
}
```

Comment: Is a list of YamlEntries, right? I ask because I tried all possibilities and it does not work.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I edit the response to be clearer

Comment: Actually, it does not work either, I modified and tried again too with List<YamlEntries>..

Error: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `objects.YamlProcessor` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (File); line: 12, column: 1]

Comment: I have just edit the answer to provide you an example on how to map the properties

Comment: Actually nope, I got on other List<> created in the list. Give me some seconds.

Comment: Everything is okey now, thank you so much for your time. But actually, is not possible to remove key "entries" from the front of all configuration from yaml file?

Comment: It is because you need to tell spring where is the list you want to map inside your configuration file. Personally, I think this way the properties file is more clear

Comment: I understand, thank you for your effort. Have a nice day!

Comment: You are welcome, however, you can rename "entries" to whatever word is more meaningful for the objects you are storing in the list